# Desire root cause is Suffering, isn't Nirvana the goal of Buddhism is a Desire?

Tags: reference-request, suffering, attachment, doubt

Subject refers, any short good answer here with an article supports? This is for in case somebody asks me this?

Comment: i think collins touches on this in his book nirvana and other buddhist felicities... i can't for the life of me remember the answer, but i would recommend the book, it is a quite excellent piece of scholarship.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Attainment of enlightenment without desire](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/9861/471)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Four Noble Truths contradicting?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/14033/471)

Comment: Desire is abandoned in dependence on desire. Nutriment is abandoned in dependence on nutriment. There is nothing special, desire is not something you hold on to after fulfilling it, one may want to reach the other shore, having reached the other shore that desire, that fuel & motivation is abandoned.